# How to I make my program a main function?

Tags: python, function, input, module, program-entry-point

I would like my program to have  a main function so I can run it as a module or main program. Main functions are new to me and I have no idea how to do this.

#!/usr/bin/python3

```
def main():
#left dashboard
    ld = raw_input("Left dashboard switch (0 or 1): ")

#right dashboard
    rd = raw_input("Right dasboard switch (0 or 1): ")

#child lock
    cl = raw_input("Child lock switch (0 or 1): ")

#master lock
    ml = raw_input("Master unlock switch (0 or 1): ")

#left inside
    li = raw_input("Left inside handle (0 or 1): ")

#left outside
    lo = raw_input("Left outside handle (0 or 1): ")

#right inside
    ri = raw_input("Right inside handle (0 or 1): ")

#right outside
    ro = raw_input("Right outside handle (0 or 1): ")

#gear shift
    gs = raw_input("Gear shift position (P, N, D , 1 ,2 ,3 or R): ")

    d = 0
    r = 0
    l = 0
    if gs == "P" and ml == "1" and cl == "0":
            d = 1
    if ri == "1" or ro == "1" or rd == "1":
            r = 1
    if li == "1" or lo == "1" or ld == "1":
            l = 1
    if d == 0:
            print "Both doors closed"
if _name_ == "_main_":
    main()
```

Comment: What is the specific issue that you're having with creating a main() function? If you just need a main() function for your script, just write a function named `main()` and call it by placing `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` at the bottom of your code.

Comment: @AdmiralWen I tried that and it says name is not defined

Comment: Sounds like you might have a problem elsewhere in your code. Can you post the exact code for which you "tried" writing the main() function and got the name error?

Comment: @AdmiralWen I updated my code to show you what ive entered.

Comment: Well, first you need to define `main()`, which I'm assuming you know? Currently your code is trying to call main() but it isn't defined, so you'll get a NameError. Secondly, both "name" and "main" is spelled with double underscores: `__name__`, not `_name_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
    #code here

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

all your  code needs to be encased in the main function. The function is them called at the bottom
[python docs - `__main__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__main__.html).
More info on main [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: I think the OP's original problem is that he typed `_name_` instead of `__name__`.

Comment: looks like it based on edit. `__name__` is required